# Combine independent queries with WITH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 separate operations:

```
MATCH ()<-[r:waitsFor]-() 
  SET r.active = true
```

and

```
MATCH (start:Job) WHERE has(start.startedAt) OR has(start.completedAt)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (prev:Job)<-[r:waitsFor]-(start:Job) 
SET r.active = false
```

They execute in about 5s for 4k nodes and 2k relations.
However if do them at once using **WITH**

```
MATCH ()<-[r:waitsFor]-() 
  SET r.active = true 
WITH null AS none
MATCH (start:Job) WHERE has(start.startedAt) OR has(start.completedAt)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (prev:Job)<-[r:waitsFor]-(start:Job) 
SET r.active = false
```

query does not execute in sensible time.
I've read **WITH** docs. What do I not understand about **WITH** that causes such behavior?

Comment: Don't you mean `WITH r`  instead of `WITH null AS none`?

Comment: No, I don't want to carry anything to second query.

Comment: Your first statement is very suspect, don't you really have any starting points or labels that this relationship is connected to?

Comment: It is simplified test model (5k nodes, 2k :waitsFor relations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. As you say, they are separate queries, so run them separately. The way you run them now, the second query is executed once for every matched result in the first. An example from a tiny ontology graph that I am working with right now with 146 nodes labeled `:OwlClass`. Consider the following two queries

**- Query 1 -**

```
MATCH (c:OwlClass) 
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

Result:

```
COUNT(*)
146
Returned 1 row in 102 ms
```

Execution plan:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE01b2d10b-7bf4-43b4-a67d-fbe826c7a4dd"], returnItemNames=["COUNT(*)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==> EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE01b2d10b-7bf4-43b4-a67d-fbe826c7a4dd,CountStar())"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>   NodeByLabel(label="OwlClass", identifier="c", _rows=146, _db_hits=0)
```

**- Query 2 -**

```
MATCH (c:OwlClass) 
WITH null as n 
MATCH (d:OwlClass) 
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

Result:

```
COUNT(*)
21316
Returned 1 row in 734 ms
```

Execution plan:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEe33d15c7-e357-4e32-9f7f-3fbc00dd58f6"], returnItemNames=["COUNT(*)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==> EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEe33d15c7-e357-4e32-9f7f-3fbc00dd58f6,CountStar())"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>   NodeByLabel(label="OwlClass", identifier="d", _rows=21316, _db_hits=0)
==>     ColumnFilter(symKeys=["c", "n"], returnItemNames=["n"], _rows=146, _db_hits=0)
==>       Extract(symKeys=["c"], exprKeys=["n"], _rows=146, _db_hits=0)
==>         NodeByLabel(label="OwlClass", identifier="c", _rows=146, _db_hits=0)
```

**- Query 3-**

```
MATCH (c:OwlClass)
WITH COUNT(c) as count_c
MATCH (d:OwlClass)
RETURN count_c, COUNT(d) as count_d
```

Result:

```
count_c   count_d
146       146
Returned 1 row in 153 ms
```

Execution plan:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["count_c", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE17be6af7-abbb-4ef7-8250-ff050d6ba7c6"], returnItemNames=["count_c", "count_d"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==> EagerAggregation(keys=["count_c"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE17be6af7-abbb-4ef7-8250-ff050d6ba7c6,Count(d))"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>   NodeByLabel(label="OwlClass", identifier="d", _rows=146, _db_hits=0)
==>     ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE67abdc54-9c44-4353-bf82-e4aff895141e"], returnItemNames=["count_c"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>       EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE67abdc54-9c44-4353-bf82-e4aff895141e,Count(c))"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>         NodeByLabel(label="OwlClass", identifier="c", _rows=146, _db_hits=0)
```

--

Read the execution plan from bottom up. The pertinent part in this case is how the number of rows changes. Compare this rough interpretation of queries 2 and 3.

**Query 2**

1. First get all nodes with label `OwlClass`. There are now 146 matched patterns.
2. Continue each pattern by setting n to null.
3. Continue each pattern by getting all nodes with label `OwlClass`. There are now 146*146=21316 matched patterns.
4. Aggregate these by counting. There is now one pattern (the count). Return it.

**Query 3**

1. First get all nodes with label `OwlClass`. There are now 146 matched patterns.
2. Aggregate these by counting. There is now one pattern (the count).
3. Continue each pattern by getting all nodes with label `OwlClass`. There are now 146 matched patterns.
4. Aggregate these by counting. There is now one pattern (the count). Return it.

Comment: Could you explain shortly the last execution plan?

Comment: Read it from bottom. First get all nodes with label `OwlClass`. There are now 146 matched patterns. Continue each pattern by setting n to null. Continue each pattern by getting all nodes with label `OwlClass`. There are now 146*146=21316 matched patterns. Aggregate these by counting. There is now one pattern (the count). Return it.

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause is used to 'carry forward' returned information to another part of the query. Using WITH null as none and moving forward to perform subsequent matches are susceptible to the creating of cartesian products within Neo4j. Depending upon the number of nodes, a cartesian product explosion could be massive and can take lots of time to go through.

So, IF the 'r' in the first query is required in the second query to narrow down the match, then you should use WITH r. Since it seems that isn't the case (because you are using WITH null as none), that may not be the solution.

Your case seems to me to be executing two separate queries in sequence. You should take a look at the [UNION](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-union.html) clause. It is used to join two queries and combine their results. The options you have are plain old `UNION` or `UNION ALL` (removes duplicates).

Comment: with null as none doesn't change the cardinality, you have to fold/aggregate the results to a smaller cardinality